# Multiple Insert transaction connection timeout - ADO.NET - SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, connection-timeout

I have a transaction with multiple inserts. All of the inserts work fine, except one.
I verified the parameters, the spelling, all of it, and it seems I'm not figuring it out.
It gives me the error:

```
Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation 
or the server is not responding.
```

My transaction looks like this:

```
SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(connString);
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
using (db)
{
    db.Open();
    SqlTransaction trans = db.BeginTransaction();
    try
    {
        //insert into COMMSignalDefinition !!Problem HERE
        da.InsertCommand = 
            new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO COMMSignalDefinition(Name) " 
                           + "VALUES (@name)", db, trans);

        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["COMMTerminalSignal"].Select())
        {
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters[0].Value = row.ItemArray[1];
            da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        // insert into COMMSignalExceptionDefinition -- names
        da.InsertCommand = 
            new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO COMMSignalExceptionDefinition(Name) " 
                           + "VALUES (@name)", db, trans);
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["COMMSignalExceptionDef"].Select())
        {
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters[0].Value = row.ItemArray[1];
            da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        trans.Commit();
        MessageBox.Show("You have successfully imported your Settings. " 
                        + "You can now exit the program.", 
                         "Success",
                         MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                         MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        trans.Rollback();
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message,
                        "Error", 
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

I have more inserts which work fine (I deleted the rest of them) and I moved the one with problems at the beginning.
 My question is what  could I possibly do wrong?
I even verified if the "problematic" query is sent to the server, with `SQL Server Profiler,` and it does! And if I execute it in `SQL Server Management studio`, it works too.

`Connection Timeout` is set to 30

Can You please give me some leads ?  SQL Server version is 2005 !
Thank You!

Comment: What's the number of records in the tables "COMMTerminalSignal" and "COMMSignalExceptionDef"? How long does it take to run this in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: COMMTerminalSignal has 2 records, COMMSignalExceptionDef (the insert works on this one) has 1 record

Comment: @Jacco It runs instantly

Comment: And running the profiler, so see 3 inserts appearing?

Comment: @Jacco yes they are appearing, since the other inserts work fine (and  the rows are added in database) when i remove the one with problems ...

Comment: "The one with problems"... Sorry, missed that part in your question. So you were already able to track this problem down to a single record? The problem does not seem to be in this code then, but in your database.

Comment: @Jacco I don't think it is in database, because the insert with problems (which actualy will "fire" twice since I have 2 records in the DataTable) is visible in SQL Server Profiler, and it's runnable instantly in Management Studio. The problem is it won't do it in C#:( If it was something in database, wouldn't I receive an exception for that ?

Comment: The last posibility is to forgot to commit a transaction, but this is my onlyone to commit here ... :( I tried to set CommandTimeout too, to  60 for ex --> the same. I'm getting angry :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of digging, it came out I did some tests in Management Studio, where I tested some transactions without committing them at all. So it was waiting for a commit, and I kept making, or trying to make inserts ... !

Comment: I would just rewrite your own answer, so it has less smileys and mark it as "The answer". I guess we've all been there more than once!

Answer (score 1):

If this is a pretty long running operation, you can try to change the [Command Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your connection string. Maybe you have some mistake in your connString var
2. Check your SqlDataAdapter command timeouts. They may be the cause of the exception (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx)
   Usually such exception is the result of either long running tasks or uncommitted transactions.

Answer (score 0):

> Connection Timeout is set to 1

[`SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx)

> The time (in **seconds**) to wait for a connection to open. The
>   default value is 15 seconds.

So you have set the timout to 1 second. Does that answer your question?

> Remarks:
>   You can set the amount of time a connection waits to time out by using
>   the ConnectTimeout or Connection Timeout keywords in the connection
>   string. **A value of 0 indicates no limit**, and should be avoided in a
>   ConnectionString because an attempt to connect waits indefinitely.

Comment: Thank You for the answer, @Tim Schmelter, but I have tried with the default Conn Time, even with 0, with the same results :(. The problem is that when I debug the code, it freezes at that line untill the exception is caught ...